# sonar-maven-plugin: extending sonar.sources in multi-module project

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I want to extend `sonar.sources`, which by default is `pom.xml,src/main/java`, by `src/main/resources` in order to check XML files that are located there.

This seemingly simple task turned out to be difficult since I have a multi-module maven project (> 100 modules, nested) with a lot of them don't have a `src/main/resources` folder and most of them not even a `src` folder (e.g. for packaging=pom). This leads to a build error if I set `sonar.sources` to `pom.xml,src/main/java,src/main/resources` or `pom.xml,src/main`:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.5:sonar (default-cli) on project xyz-parent: The directory 'C:\...\submodule\src\main\resources' does not exist for Maven module ... Please check the property sonar.sources -> [Help 1]
```

The sonar-maven-plugin itself uses `${project.build.sourceDirectory}` to do it right in every module.

I tried to use regular expressions to set `sonar.sources` to `src/main` by cutting off `/java` (or `\java` on Windows) via

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.7</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>regex-property</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>regex-property</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <name>sonar.sources</name>
        <value>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</value>
        <regex>[/\\]+java$</regex>
        <replacement></replacement>
        <failIfNoMatch>false</failIfNoMatch>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

But this does nothing and I have no idea to which lifecycle phase I should bind it to have it executed.

Or is there a way to avoid the error due to missing directory in `sonar.sources`? According to [current sonar-maven source](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-maven/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/bootstrap/MavenProjectConverter.java#L433) missing directories are only ignored if the POM has `pom` packaging but not for `ear` or `jar` modules without resources.

Or should I ensure `src/main` exists before sonar start? What hook may I use for that?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

One of the things you can do it:

- In your root POM, define the following properties:

  - `sonar.sources` to be `.`
  - `sonar.inclusions` to be `src/main/**`
  - => this will include all the known files that SQ finds in your modules in the `src/main` folder if it exists
- In your modules, if you want to control better what gets in, you just have to use/override `sonar.exclusions` or `sonar.inclusions`

Comment: Thanks! I have set `sonar.inclusions` to `pom.xml,src/main/**` and it works just the way it should.I think it would be an improvement for the [documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters) if `sonar.exclusions` were not only discussed in the context of [Narrowing the Focus](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus).